# Setting Up Prebid and Receiving CORB Error

Tags: cors, prebid.js, cross-origin-read-blocking

We're setting up prebid in our local environment with four ad networks; we aren't able to see ads.

I think it's possible that we haven't seen ads because of our local environment, but we're also seeing the ad below.

```js
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/adview?ai=CzJ-9F0shW-7gKMj0-QP47YOQA97b-JFS5vHE8psHwI23ARABINGH0iBgyd74hsij6BmgAezprP8CyAEC4AIAqAMByAOZBKoEygFP0NBysRA0tLgwsgOml3PLPkm7yeGllYSfrEI4KYzuge5CkRTMSG_L2x2PRFevb3-01ht38BRruNB8m4zFcB2gbarxmwFcfohrQPX_mTsRwKpfrcuhQctY7FJ4L2v98E5JjqHXbgIC0GiGA6ok-cyq5AmUs4nTyXrPEi_SyQSO0jwdm2W_flNYF6SfN7nE3eBmxyuFg1YFwN-mOj_rw4_MIlUCOgi5XJ4Ci2gZV2FPOGVOINdWRgt9gBIq-u6u7XqBfhtfrP4UrtwMwASm1OKb4AHgBAGSBQQIBBgBkgUECAUYBKAGAoAH_7LRgAGoB47OG6gHjc0bqAfVyRuoB9nLG6gHz8wbqAemvhuoB5jOG6gH6c0b2AcB8gcEEKu0NtIIBwiAYRABGAHyCBthZHgtc3Vic3luLTI3NDYxMjc1MjcwMjgxNTaACgPYEww&sigh=TQAyHYAsHSo&dpt=1 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!